# SQL Reporting Services 2005 not Showing Contents or Properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I installed and configured SQL Server 2005 with Reporting Services, Workgroup Edition on Windows 7. I have updated to Service Pack 4. The problem is that when I navigate to http://localhost/reports/Pages/Folder.aspx, Reporting Services don't show/display Contents or Properties menus, all I see is the SQL Server Reporting Services header with the Home/Help button.

EDIT: I figured it out. You need to create role assignments that explicitly grant you access together with full permissions. To do this, follow these steps:
Start Internet Explorer together with the Run as administrator option. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, right-click Internet Explorer, and then click Run as administrator.
Open Report Manager. By default, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports.

If you use SQL Server Express with Advanced Services SP2, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$sqlexpress. If you use a named instance of Reporting Services, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$InstanceName
In the Home dialog box, click Properties.
Click New Role Assignment.
Type a Windows user account name by using the following format:
Domain\User
Click to select the Content Manager check box.
Click OK.
In the Home dialog box, click Site Settings.
Click Configure site-wide security.
Click New Role Assignment.
Type a Windows user account by using the following format:
Domain\User
Click System Administrator.
Click OK.
Close Report Manager.

Comment: You can answer your own question. That would be acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to create role assignments that explicitly grant you access together with full permissions. To do this, follow these steps: Start Internet Explorer together with the Run as administrator option. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, right-click Internet Explorer, and then click Run as administrator. Open Report Manager. By default, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports.

If you use SQL Server Express with Advanced Services SP2, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$sqlexpress. If you use a named instance of Reporting Services, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$InstanceName In the Home dialog box, click Properties. Click New Role Assignment. Type a Windows user account name by using the following format: Domain\User Click to select the Content Manager check box. Click OK. In the Home dialog box, click Site Settings. Click Configure site-wide security. Click New Role Assignment. Type a Windows user account by using the following format: Domain\User Click System Administrator. Click OK. Close Report Manager.